# An editor that generates PHP docblocks

Tags: php, macos, ide, text-editor, osx-lion

In NetBeans, if I have, say

```
function myCmp ($a, $b) {
    return $a['col_a'] > $b['col_b'] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

and then I go to the line above it, type `/**` and press enter, NetBeans inserts a docblock like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param type $a
 * @param type $b
 * @return type 
 */
function myCmp ($a, $b) {
    return $a['col_a'] > $b['col_b'] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

That's really nice. But on the whole, NetBeans drives me up the wall with its non-standard (for a Mac user) responses to mouse and KB inputs.

I've tried Aptana, TextMate, BBedit and Sublime Text 2, which are all splendid, but they don't generate docbloc tags from the function's signature like NetBeans.

What other editors should I try? Or am I using the ones mentioned incorrectly?

I'm on OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

And the good news is that there is now a plugin for sublime text 2 that does this

https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

It is called JSdocs, but it works for PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember well [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) is doing the same thing as Netbeans for Docblock.
Moreover you can customize it in templates

Answer (score 0):

[PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) can also generate doc comments and will also infer types as much as possible. For example it would recognize that the return type is `int`.

Note though that PhpStorm is not a free IDE.

Comment: I've been trying it out. Feels a lot like BetBeans somehow. Will take a lot of learning.